# Citation in TeXMaker new version

Tags: bibliography, texmaker

I have reinstalled TexMaker Editor and every time I try to use my .bib file for citations, I only see the ?? instead. I made sure I change the settings in the Quick Build to include the right one but nothing happens. I use the proper packages (I've already used them in a previous .tex file which works perfectly fine). The old file was created on the old version of TexMaker.

Alternatively, does anyone know ow to use a .bib bibliography on Overleaf?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzE3n.png)

Comment: I guess you should ask this in https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Wasn't aware of this. Thank you. Will do now.